# how to plot categorical data?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, plot, seaborn

Basically data contains information about the `machine` being used by `operators` for specific `activity`

```
df.head()
```

I have data like as follows:

```
machine_name                activity                      Operator_name     start_datetime       end_datetime   reasons_for_break   duration
Yash [HMC]           PILLAR SUB ASSY MOUNTING ON BASE      Abhishek     2018-10-10 00:50:20 2018-10-10 11:51:23                       661
IMPERIAL             SPINDLE MOTOR ASSEMBLY AND MOUNTING    Abijith     2018-10-10 11:44:00 2018-10-10 12:26:42                        42
V.R                  SPINDLE MOTOR ASSEMBLY AND MOUNTING    Abijith     2018-10-10 11:21:02 2018-10-10 12:26:27                        65
Gnutti Carlo-2[HMC]   ATC MOUNTING ON MACHINE BASE        Anantha Ramu  2018-10-10 00:54:59 2018-10-10 00:55:45                         0
Gnutti Carlo-2[HMC]      SPINDLE MOUNTING                 Anantha Ramu  2018-10-10 00:57:04 2018-10-10 00:58:55    MFD mistake          1
MMF-3[HMC]          APC SUB ASSY MOUNTING ON BASE            Ashok      2018-10-10 09:27:41 2018-10-10 12:04:31    APC UP DOWN         56
MMF-3[HMC]              IT/DDRT MOUNTING ON BASE             Ashok      2018-10-10 13:45:16 2018-10-10 15:13:30                        88
Gnutti Carlo-2[HMC] PILLAR SUB ASSY MOUNTING ON BASE       Balamurali   2018-10-10 09:17:04 2018-10-10 12:21:25                        184
Gnutti Carlo-2[HMC] PILLAR SUB ASSY MOUNTING ON BASE       Balamurali   2018-10-10 12:21:25 2018-10-10 13:18:54    Tea break            57
```

the problem is all the columns are `categorical` datatype expect `start_datetime` & `end_datetime` which are `datetime` format and `duration` is in `integer` datatype.

How these data can be `plotted` showing all the information it have??

I tried with seaborn as:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.lmplot( x="Operator_name", y="duration", data=df, fit_reg=False, hue='machine_name', legend=True)
```

but got error as :

`Categorical is not ordered for operation min`

How could I plot and show information of this data ??

Tried below code :

```
sns.catplot(x = 'Operator_name' , y = 'duration', hue ='nick_name' , data = df)
```

Got a plot with overlapping x axis

[image: x axis overlapping]

Comment: What do you want to plot exactly? What information do you want to display with your visualization?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Dummy DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Operator_name':["Abhishek"]*4 + ['Abijith']*5 + ['Anamtha Ramu']*3,
                  'Duration': np.random.randint(10, 200, size = 12)})
df.head()

    Operator_name   Duration
0   Abhishek         153
1   Abhishek         188
2   Abhishek         51
3   Abhishek         189
4   Abijith          188
```

You could use groupby:

```
df1 = df.groupby('Operator_name').sum().reset_index()
df1

    Operator_name        Duration
0   Abhishek              299
1   Abijith               458
2   Anamtha Ramu          343
```

Use the [DataFrame.plot.bar](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html) function

```
df1.plot.bar(x = 'Operator_name', y='Duration')
```

You can also use matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.bar(df['Operator_name'], df['Duration'])
```

For Seaborn, give the following code a try:

```
sns.barplot(x = df['Operator_name'], y = df['Duration'], hue = df['machine_name'])
```

Comment: I would also include `machine_name` as `hue` for `groupby` plot ...is it possible ??

Comment: any alternative method using seaborn ??

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Using the seaborn way...the `Operator_name` in x axis are overlapping ...can it be corrected ??

Comment: updated the image in main question. Kindly have a look

Comment: @suryarahul  The hue is working as intended. What are you exactly expecting?

Comment: See the x axis where the names are overlapping ...could it be resolved ??